# PHP arraym map and method of item class

Tags: php, array-map

I have array:

```
array(
  0 => new SomeClass(1),
  1 => new SomeClass(2),
  2 => new SomeClass(3),
)
```

How can I use array map to call method (non-static) of SomeClass class for each item in my array?

Comment: Do you need to use array_map specifically? or would a foreach not do?

Comment: Why are you using `array_map()` instead of a `foreach` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a more readable way than [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) or [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk):

```
$instances = array(
  0 => new SomeClass(1),
  1 => new SomeClass(2),
  2 => new SomeClass(3),
)

foreach($instances as $instance)
{
    $instance->foo();
}
```

but if you really want `array_map`:

```
array_map(function($instance) {
    $instance->foo();
}, $instances);
```